# Integrate google map android

Tags: android

I'm developing an app and I'm trying to integrate to my app a google map. I'm reading that I need to create a special app at the beggining. I tried to ignore it and tried to integrate it anyway. But when I try to extend my class with MapActivity, it doesn't find it. I generated the Key, Google Play Service is up to date. I probably miss something.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

MapActivity was part of the Google Maps Android v1 API which is now deprecated.

Use MapFragment if possible

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/

Comment: Ok thanks but the thing is I already have my app and I don't know how to integrate it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You need the new integration in Google map you want to use the new Google map api in android.

So follow below link for integration google map with "MapFragment".
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm